# Why a Precision problem for Floor of quotient of Logs?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

This line returns a Precision problem:

```
Floor[Log[9]/Log[3]]
```

This one works fine:

```
Floor[Log[9]/Log[3]//N]
```

What I don't understand is why one works while the other doesn't because I assume that internally *Mathematica* would numerically evaluate the argument of `Floor` first anyway, so the two lines should be logically equivalent, the 2nd one just redundant. But clearly I was wrong. What did I misunderstand about how `Floor` works?

Comment: Not an answer, but try `Floor[Log[9]/Log[3]] // FullSimplify`. -- Interesting, `N` also works: `N[Floor[Log[9]/Log[3]]]`.

Comment: Maybe after an initial estimate of `2`, it tries to determine whether it is greater than or less than `2`.  This gives a similar error: `N[Log[9]/Log[3] - 2, 30]`.

Comment: `Floor` is discontinuous at the integers. Any attempt to use numeric methods on an exact example will have trouble there.That's what the message indicates.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  But what is happening differently in the two lines of code I presented?

Comment: The second one has numericized with `N` before `Floor` sees it, so it is no longer an exact computation for `Floor`. If the numericization gives 2.0 or that plus an ULP, `Floor` will give 2; if it gives 2.0 minus an ULP then `Floor` will give 1. What `Floor` will not do is trouble itself over how the machine value came about or the fact that it is "near" a discontinuity.

Comment: as an example `Floor[ Log[36]/Log[6] // N ] (*1*)`

Answer (score 6):

While the comments already contain a complete answer by [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau), this behavior is also documented on [`ref/Floor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Floor.html), see the first example under 'Possible Issues':

> Floor does not automatically resolve the value:
>
> ```
> Floor[π^2 + 2 π + 1 - (π + 1)^2]
>
> (* Floor::meprec: Internal precision limit
> $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating Floor[1+2π+π^2-(1+π)^2]. *)
>
> (* Floor[1 + 2 π + π^2 - (1 + π)^2] *)
> ```

Even though `1 + 2 π + π^2 - (1 + π)^2` is in fact the *exact* integer 0, it is a "hidden zero" which cannot be unmasked using purely numerical methods.

Unlike other functions like `FullSimplify` and `PossibleZeroQ` which may use symbolic algorithms, `Floor` is limited to numerical methods, see also this documentation note

> For exact numeric quantities, `Floor` internally uses numerical approximations to establish its result.

and the numerical approximation will never yield an exact zero, no matter how much extra precision is allowed, e.g.

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000}, N[π^2 + 2 π + 1 - (π + 1)^2, 50]]
```

Similarly, `Log[9]/Log[3]` is a "hidden integer". Numerical approximation of the exact quantity `Log[9]/Log[3] - 2` is difficult, while numerical approximation of the machine precision number `N[Log[9]/Log[3]] - 2` is not.