# Table to generate colossally abundant numbers not working

Tags: warning-messages, list-manipulation, precision-and-accuracy

I'm trying to tabulate the first `8` [`colossally abundant numbers`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossally_abundant_number) defined by critical epsilon values, with epsilon listed in descending order (Broughan lists the first few [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vgRADwAAQBAJ&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=critical%20epsilon%20values%20colossally%20abundant%20numbers&source=bl&ots=jXqEaao48O&sig=ACfU3U2oQgxF91l8pcnkMAEdrjgbVxCzbQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHzcTrmO7kAhVIRhUIHV5gD-YQ6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=critical%20epsilon%20values%20colossally%20abundant%20numbers&f=false), although note that the errata for his book [here](https://www.math.waikato.ac.nz/~kab/ERH/ERHerrata.pdf) add one missing critical epsilon value, which I have included in the list below). I'm listing them in `TeXForm` form simply because it's easier to decipher visually. However, the same values are already entered in the Mathematica code that follows. Those epsilon values are

$\epsilon_1=\frac{\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\log (2)}$, 
$\epsilon_2=\frac{\log \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}{\log (3)}$, 
$\epsilon_3=\frac{\log \left(\frac{7}{6}\right)}{\log (2)}$, 
$\epsilon_4=\frac{\log \left(\frac{6}{5}\right)}{\log (5)}$, 
$\epsilon_5=\frac{\log \left(\frac{15}{14}\right)}{\log (2)}$, 
$\epsilon_6=\frac{\log \left(\frac{13}{12}\right)}{\log (3)}$, 
$\epsilon_7=\frac{\log \left(\frac{8}{7}\right)}{\log (7)}$, 
$\epsilon_8=\frac{\log \left(\frac{31}{302}\right)}{\log (2)}$

I compose these into a table...

```
Quiet[
   xList = Range[8];
   caNumbers = {2, 6, 12, 60, 120, 360, 2520, 5040}; 
   epsilon =
       Table[ϵ, {ϵ, {Log[3/2]/Log[2], Log[4/3]/Log[3],
       Log[7/6]/Log[2],  Log[6/5]/Log[5], Log[15/14]/Log[2], Log[13/12]/Log[3],
       Log[8/7]/Log[7],  Log[31/30]/Log[2]}}];
   epsilonN =
       Table[N[ϵ], {ϵ, {Log[3/2]/Log[2], Log[4/3]/Log[3],
       Log[7/6]/Log[2],  Log[6/5]/Log[5], Log[15/14]/Log[2], Log[13/12]/Log[3],
       Log[8/7]/Log[7],  Log[31/30]/Log[2]}}];
   colossalNumber = 
       Table[N[Product[p^(Floor[ Log[(p^(1 + ϵ) - 1)/
       (p^ϵ - 1)]/Log[p]] -  1), 
       {p, Prime[Range[25]]}]], {ϵ, {Log[3/2]/Log[2], Log[4/3]/Log[3],
       Log[7/6]/Log[2],  Log[6/5]/Log[5], Log[15/14]/Log[2], Log[13/12]/Log[3],
       Log[8/7]/Log[7],  Log[31/30]/Log[2]}}]; 
   criticalEpsilonValueTable = 
       Transpose[
       Join[{xList, epsilon, epsilonN, N[colossalNumber], caNumbers}, 2]]; 
   TableForm[criticalEpsilonValueTable,
       TableHeadings -> {None, {"x", "ϵ", "ϵ (numeric)",
       "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(n\), \(ϵ\)]\) ∈ CA", 
       "xth CA number"}}]
   ]
```

...and the value of `n` for `x = 3` is wrong. In fact, the third CA number is missing entirely:

[image]

Larger tables produce similar results - missing values of `n`.

It's possible I've made some mathematical error; I am aware that there is more than one CA number associated with each critical value of epsilon. But the numbers listed under `xth CA number` are the lowest of each set... So, I wonder if it's to do with machine precision?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `Floor` is unable to return an exact result for `Log[8]/Log[2]`, which is why you needed to use Quiet:

```
Floor[Log[8]/Log[2]]
```

> Floor::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating Floor[Log[8]/Log[2]].
>
> Floor[Log[8]/Log[2]]

Then, you used `N` which converts the argument to an approximate machine number result. Unfortunately, the approximate machine number is ever so slightly smaller than 3:

```
N[Log[8]/Log[2]] //InputForm
```

> 2.9999999999999996

This is why you get an incorrect result. See this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138307/45431) which discusses the issue further. As a workaround, you could use the following substitute for `Floor`

```
floor[e_] := Quiet@Check[Floor[e], Floor[FullSimplify[e]]]
```

Then:

```
Table[
    Product[p^(floor[Log[(p^(1+ϵ)-1)/(p^ϵ-1)]/Log[p]]-1),{p, Prime[Range[25]]}],
    {ϵ, epsilon}
]
```

> {2, 6, 12, 60, 120, 360, 2520, 5040}

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) rather than [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html)

```
xList = Range[8];

caNumbers = {2, 6, 12, 60, 120, 360, 2520, 5040};

epsilon = {Log[3/2]/Log[2], Log[4/3]/Log[3], Log[7/6]/Log[2], Log[6/5]/Log[5],
    Log[15/14]/Log[2], Log[13/12]/Log[3], Log[8/7]/Log[7], Log[31/30]/Log[2]};

colossalNumber = 
  Table[Product[
      p^(Floor[Log[(p^(1 + ϵ) - 1)/(p^ϵ - 1)]/Log[p]] - 
         1), {p, Prime[Range[25]]}] // FullSimplify, {ϵ, epsilon}] //
    Quiet;

criticalEpsilonValueTable = 
  Transpose[Join[{xList, epsilon, epsilon // N, colossalNumber, caNumbers}, 
    2]];

TableForm[criticalEpsilonValueTable, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"x", "ϵ", "ϵ (numeric)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(n\), \(ϵ\)]\) ∈ CA", 
    "xth CA number"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to say "FullSimplify instead of N"?

Comment: Yes, I'll correct. Thanks

Comment: Hello both. Incredibly useful feedback, thank you. @Bob Hanlon, your answer is fantastic and incredibly useful. I feel obliged given the similarity of both answers to mark the first as the answer. But I'm very grateful to you both.